# PHP member changes after recursive call

Tags: php, class, recursion, member

Here is a simplefied code:

```
Class Bar
{
    static $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->loop($foo,1);
    }

    public function loop(Foo $foo, $index)
    {   

        $a = $foo->a;
        if ($index < 3)
        {
            $a[$index]->var2 += $a[$index]->var1;
            $a[$index]->var1 = 0;
            $foo->dump();
            $this->foo->dump();

            $this->loop(new Foo($a),++$index);
        }
    }
}

$p = array(
      new Baz(100,200),
      new Baz(300,400),
      new Baz(400,200),
      new Baz(600,400)
    );

new Bar(new Foo($p));
```

There are two problem with this code. maybe more;)

1. It looks like that the reallocation of var1 has an affect on $foo. I would expect that after i passed $foo->a to $a it doesnt have.
2. In the construct i assaigned $foo to $this->foo but after every loop it changes its value. Could some point me out where does $this->foo's value change?

**Some more Info**
Definition of Foo Class

```
Class Foo
{
    public $a;
    public function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
    public function dump($title="")
    {
        echo "<br/>================".$title."=============================";
        echo "<table>";
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->a); $i++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $this->a[$i]->var1 . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $this->a[$i]->var2 . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
```

The Baz Class

```
Class Baz
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public function __construct($var1, $var2)
    {
        $this->var1=$var1;
        $this->var2=$var2;
    }

}
```

The results of dumps:

```
================IM foo dump=============================
100 200
0   700
400 200
600 400

================Im $this->foo dump=====================
100 200
0   700
400 200
600 400

================IM foo dump=============================
100 200
0   700
0   600
600 400

================Im $this->foo dump======================
100 200
0   700
0   600
600 400
```

Comment: Can you post the class definition of Foo as well?

Comment: Why are you referencing `static $foo` with the `this` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is normal. When assigning objects to variables in PHP, you pass a reference, not the value; if you want to have copies instead of references, you have to [create a clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

For instance, in the following scenario:

```
$blub = new Bar();
$a = $blub;
$b = $blub;
$c = $blub;
```

$a, $b, $c are just "aliases" so to speak, that point to $blub; meaning setting any member of $a has a direct effect on $blub, and therefore $b and $c aswell.

By using the keyword clone however you can achieve the result you are looking for:

```
$blub = new Bar();
$a = clone $blub;
$b = clone $blub;
$c = clone $blub;
```

Here we have explicitly created independent copies, and thus modifying the contents of $a will not change $blub, $b, or $c.

Finally here's how your example class could look like implementing clones to work on standalone objects:

```
Class Bar
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->loop(clone $foo, 1);
    }

    public function loop(Foo $foo, $index)
    {   
        $a = array();

        foreach($foo->a as $key => $subobject) {
            $a[$key] = clone $subobject;
        }

        if ($index < 3)
        {
            $a[$index]->var2 += $a[$index]->var1;
            $a[$index]->var1 = 0;
            $foo->dump();
            $this->foo->dump();

            $this->loop(new Foo($foo->a),++$index);
        }
    }
}


new Bar(new Foo($p));
```

### Update

Simply cloning $foo was not enough due to the fact that an array of objects is passed around:

```
$p = array(
      new Baz(100,200),
      new Baz(300,400),
      new Baz(400,200),
      new Baz(600,400)
    );
```

Even if you clone the object which hosts the array, the objects themselves within the array still point to the same objects, since the array is just holding references; when an object is cloned, array members and their contents are copied, including references. It takes a bit to get your head around the concepts of references and values but eventually you'll see everything fits like a puzzle :)

Anyhow, in this specific case one has to clone the objects within the array before using them, and this is easily achieved with the following loop inside the Bar::loop function:

```
        foreach($a as $key => $subobject) {
            $a[$key] = clone $subobject;
        }
```

See the class above for the complete edit.

Comment: thanks but i got Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in the $a = clone $foo->a; line. $foo-> is an array. in my example $p. (see the added information)

Comment: try $fooclone = clone $foo; $a = $fooclone->a; (see edited class)

Comment: I have edited the opening post. There u find every code i have. 3 classes, an array ($p) holds the Baz's and new Bar(new Foo($p)); Thats all i have. It should produce the same output i posted

Comment: Found and updated; tl;dr version, see the class in the post which I have updated aswell.

Comment: ty very much for ur help!It makes sense! I have learned again something;). BTW i found an another solution. Mybe someon interrested:$this->foo = unserialize(serialize($foo));

Comment: Yeah, that results in a clone of the object, using the clone keyword should be more efficient though.

Comment: By the way I just added a minor fix; use $this->loop(new Foo($foo->a),++$index); instead of $this->loop(new Foo($a),++$index);